# How to load a spring beans which are in jar file in projects lib folder

Tags: spring

How can I load a spring beans which are in jar file say for eg. sample.jar with all the beans declared in that jar with sample-applicationContext.xml?

Now I am using some of the beans from this jar in my project so when I deploy my ear file this sample.jar is in lib folder. Now when I deploy this project to server(jboss -5) it is not injecting the bean i have referenced in my main project.

we dont have any web app in this ear so the way we are loading beans are using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. Can somebody gave me an example of how to load those beans from sample.jar(lib folder) first and then load those are in the project, so when spring creates beans in the main project it will have beans from sample.jar and would inject them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Beans are looked-up on the classpath, so if they are annotated and your have the proper component scan, they should be discovered.

If they are not annotated, but only listed in the `sample-applicationContext.xml`, then you can `<import resource="classpath:sample-applicationContext.xml" />`

Comment: I tried this settings and I am still getting BeanCreationException. What else could be the problem? Because if I see in my jar there is sample-applicationContext.xml and all the directory structure is correct. Also when I see the server log I can see that Spring is trying to load beans from the sample-applicationContext.xml and then it is thrwoing BeanCreationException

Comment: @user509755 what is the root cause of that exception? Paste the whole stacktrace.